# How to add custom total row in Invoice PDF

Tags: magento-2.1, invoice, pdf, totals

I added `pdf.xml` in custom modules etc folder. But it is not reflecting in Invoice PDF.
I have debug and found that in the class `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf`, on line no. 676 I get custom row values but those row values gets omitted after the statement `$total->setOrder($order)->setSource($source);`

```
protected function insertTotals($page, $source)
    {
        $order = $source->getOrder();
        $totals = $this->_getTotalsList();
        $lineBlock = ['lines' => [], 'height' => 15];
        foreach ($totals as $total) {
            echo "<pre>";print_r($total->getData());// I get custom row values here
            $total->setOrder($order)->setSource($source);//But those get lost here
```

This is a protected function so I cannot add plugin also.

**EDIT**

`Pdf.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/pdf_file.xsd">
    <totals>
        <total name="custfee">
            <title translate="true">Custom Fee</title>
            <font_size>7</font_size>
            <display_zero>true</display_zero>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        </total>
    </totals>
</config>
```

Comment: Can you share the code of pdf.xml first.

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

To include a custom total row in pdf, we need to enter the details of the custom row which we need to show in sales/pdf.xml.

> **For example:** Giftwrapping amount will not show in the Invoice Print PDF.  To show the Giftwrapping amount in PDF, add the below code
>   in pdf.xml. Copy the pdf.xml (vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/pdf.xml)
>   from the vendor and put in a custom module and add only the below code
>   in the ***pdf.xml*** file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/pdf_file.xsd">
    <totals>
        <total name="magento_giftcardaccount_wrapping">
            <title translate="true">Gift Wrapping for Items</title>
            <source_field>gw_items_price</source_field>
            <font_size>7</font_size>
            <display_zero>false</display_zero>
            <sort_order>450</sort_order>
        </total>
    </totals>
</config>
```

In this way, we can add custom row total in the pdf totals section.

Add the field name from the table which we need to show in the *source_field*, *display_zero* is used to show this row total even the value is 0, we can give any name in the *name* field.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

After debugging the `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf::insertTotals()`:

```
$total->setOrder($order)->setSource($source);
```

On this line, Magento simply sets two Objects data to the current total object for using later. You can get the Order and Source (Invoice object - `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice`) data:

```
$total->getOrder()->getData(); // Order data
$total->getSource()->getData(); // Invoice data
//Get specific data from total object
$total->getSourceField();
$total->getSortOrder();
```

[image]

If we're trying to var dump or print the total object, the page can be crashed because this object is "heavy" after set order and invoice source object.

**I think your problem comes `$total->canDisplay()` or `$total->getTotalsForDisplay()`.**

1) `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\DefaultTotal::canDisplay()`. This method will check:

- Amount is not equal to zero.
- Or, in your `pdf.xml` config, you have declare `<display_zero>true</display_zero>`. Set to `true` if you want to display zero amount.

2) `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\DefaultTotal::getTotalsForDisplay()`: Get array of arrays with totals information for displaying in PDF